# joining data from two table then using the fulldata to add it to a questionnaire responses

Tags: r, join, dplyr, dataset

I'm struggling a little bit to join some data together. I have 2 sets of data :

- Sub_all_hard = 165 entries and four columns (subj_id, gender, age, language)
- Sub_all_easy = 164 entries and four columns same as above.
  I tried to do bind_rows and it says :
  Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.

- Size 164: Column `y`.
- Size 165: Column `x`.
  i Only values of size one are recycled.

Once I join them I need to add the data to another one which is a questionnaire that all the subj_id responded too and I feel like I can't make it with my actual level. Any help to explain how

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Provide your data via the output of `dput(df)`.

Comment: Are you sure the error is with `bind_rows` and not one of your inputs you're trying to bind? That error is associated with trying to make a `tibble` which has *columns* of unequal length - `tibble(b=2:1, a=3:1)`